# Change navbar background color on other routes in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, dynamic, colors, routes

I have following react code.

[the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-villani-dttby?file=/src/components/Navbar.js)

What I would like is to just when I click on "about" menu background color should change from red to blue otherwise stay in red.

in another scenario:
(my problem is how to access to links "route" or "path" in react because i want to add condition like ==> if (path =="./about) do somthing...)

is there any way to do this? i would appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are  using `react-router-dom`

Then you can use the useLocation hook to get the current location

First import it

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then get the location

```
const location = useLocation();
```

You can use a `useEffect` hook to change the background color whenever the location changes

```
useEffect(()=>
    { 
        if(location.pathname == '/about'){
        // Change background color
        }
    }
},[location])
```

This should work for you

Try to include this code in your `App.js`

Comment: Tnx for your help  i never used useLocation hook before is there any way to use it in css component file like NavbarStyle.js directly?

Answer (score 2):

Following code works:

```html
const Nav = styled.nav`
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  /* background-color: red; */
`;

const Menu = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Navbar = ({ toggle }) => {
  const [navBg, setNavBg] = React.useState("red");
  const location = useLocation();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.pathname === "/about") {
      setNavBg("yellow");
    } else {
      setNavBg('red')
    }
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <Nav style={{ backgroundColor: navBg }}>
      <h1 to="/">logo</h1>
      <Menu>
        <Link to="/">home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">about</Link>
        <Link to="/services">services</Link>
      </Menu>
    </Nav>
```

Comment: Tnx man this worked perfectly!  one extra question, i used external css components in my project such as NavbarStyle.js how can i pass state to that navbarstyle component and use it in that file?

Comment: You can pass props to a child component : `export function ChildComponent({yourState}){};` and call it like so : `<ChildComponent yourState={myState} />`